# Add new Window from C# Code-Behind in ext.net

Tags: c#, dynamic, ext.net

I'd like to add a new `Window` with working `Listeners` and `DirectEvents` from code-behind to realize an admin-interface on Button-Click. So far I have following Code (minimalized):

```
Window editwindow = new Window(){
   ID="Window_Edit",
   width = 380,
   height = 120,
   hidden = false
};
FormPanel editpanel = new FormPanel(){
   ID="Panel_Edit"
}; 
editpanel.Items.Add(new TextField(){
   ID="Edit_Fieldname",
   FieldLabel = "Some Label",
   LabelStyle="text-align:right;",
   Width = 260,
   LabelWidth=120
});
editwindow.Add(editpanel);
this.Page.Controls.Add(editwindow);
//Viewport.Add(editwindow); Viewport is a wrapping <ext:Container>
//editwindow.DoLayout(); this has been throwing a reference error on client-side
```

I'd like to know how I can make the window be displayed. Right now if I inspect the execution with firebug a status code `200: OK` is returned on the Post Request. But I do a Store operation some lines before that, and the response does not Contain these Store Changes!

The funny thing now is, that changing the triggering Button's Text works without fault, so I am sure a full reload is not executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making a few assumptions with my response because you have not posted a sample demonstrating the whole scenario, but I think revising to the following should work:

```
// Old
// editwindow.Add(editpanel);
// this.Page.Controls.Add(editwindow);

// New
editwindow.Items.Add(editpanel);
editwindow.Render(this.Form);
```

The following sample also demonstrates the scenario of dynamically creating a Window during a DirectEvent and adding the , see

http://examples.ext.net/#/XRender/Basic/New_Window/

Hope this helps.